# R Surface Plot from List of X,Y,Z points

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to make a surface plot for data that is in a very long list of x,y,z points.  To do this, I am dividing the data into a grid of 10k squares and finding the max value of z within each square.  From my understanding, each z value should be stored in a matrix where each element of the matrix corresponds to a square on the grid.  Is there an easier way to do this than the code below?  That last line is already pretty long and it is only one square.

```
x<-(sequence(101)-1)*max(eff$CFaR)/100
y<-(sequence(101)-1)*max(eff$EaR)/100
effmap<-matrix(ncol=length(x)-1, nrow=length(y)-1)
someMatrix <- max(eff$Cost[which(eff$EaR[which(eff$CFaR >= x[50] & eff$CFaR <x[51], arr.ind=TRUE)]>=y[20] & eff$EaR[which(eff$CFaR >= x[50] & eff$CFaR <x[51], arr.ind=TRUE)]< y[91])])
```

Comment: Yes, there's an easier way. Provide either a representative sample of your data (`eff`) - e.g big enough so that a working result can be produced, or upload all of it and provide a link.

Comment: here is a link to the first 10k rows of eff:
[link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0F1yWDNKi2vSHF1aFV6TENrNjQ/edit?usp=docslist_api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is my interpretation of what you are trying to accomplish...

```
df   <- read.csv("effSample.csv")            # downloaded from your link
df   <- df[c("CFaR","EaR","Cost")]           # remove unnecessary columns
df$x <- cut(df$CFaR,breaks=100,labels=FALSE) # establish bins: CFaR
df$y <- cut(df$EaR,breaks=100,labels=FALSE)  # establish bins: EaR

df.max <- expand.grid(x=1:100,y=1:100)       # template; 10,000 grid cells
# maximum cost in each grid cell - NOTE: most of the cells are *empty*
df.max <- merge(df.max,aggregate(Cost~x+y,df,max),all.x=TRUE)
z <- matrix(df.max$Cost,nr=100,nc=100)       # Cost vector -> matrix
# colors based on z-value
palette <- rev(rainbow(20))                  # palette of 20 colors
zlim    <- range(z[!is.na(z)])
colors  <- palette[19*(z-zlim[1])/diff(zlim) + 1] 
# create the plot
library(rgl)
open3d(scale=c(1,1,10))  # CFaR and EaR range ~ 10 X Cost range
x.values <- min(df$CFaR)+(0:99)*diff(range(df$CFaR))/100
y.values <- min(df$EaR)+(0:99)*diff(range(df$EaR))/100
surface3d(x.values,y.values,z,col=colors)
axes3d()
title3d(xlab="CFaR",ylab="EaR",zlab="Cost")
```

[image]

The code above generates a rotatable 3D plot, so the image is just a screen shot. Notice how there are lots of "holes". This is (partially) because you provided only part of your data. However, it is important to realize that just because you imagine 10,000 grid cells (e.g., a 100 X 100 grid), does not mean that there will be data in every cell.